# bptest result different from manual calculation result

Tags: r

I have a model "model1" its a linear probability model. It measures the chance that of a woman working before and after 1993 taking into consideration whether or not she has children.
So model 1 is -

```
Y = B0 + B1 mother + B2 after + B3 mother * after + epsilon
```

Where mother = 1 if the woman has children. And after = 1 if the year is 1993 or after. The Y is a dummy variable that equals 1 if a woman works. I ran the model and I got the result. 
After that I conducted a bptest -

```
bptest(model1,studentize=TRUE)

studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  model1
BP = 20.764, df = 3, p-value = 0.0001178
```

However, when I run the regression -

```
residuals(squared) = B0 + B1 mother + B2 after + B3 after mother
```

I don't get the same F value as the BP test. The F value is big enough to indicate Heteroskedasticity but it isn't the same as the BP value.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you get from `lmtest::bptest` is not **F**, but result for **LM = n * R^2**, where **R^2** is from `residuals^2 = B0 + B1 mother ...`